# Quick redirection of console I/O for a C# application

Tags: c#, console

I believe this is a well known issue of recent versions of Visual Studio IDE. If we try to put redirect commands in the "Command line arguments" box of the "Start Options" of the "Project Properties" page, like ">output.txt", then we get into trouble.

We can get a workaround by unchecking "Enable the visual Studio hosting process" checkbox, but when we start the program "without debugging" (control-F5), the redirect doesn't work and ">output.txt" is returned as a program argument.

The question is: how can we do the redirect to work in all configurations?

Well, searching StackOverflow I found some options, and I devised a mean to do a quick and dirty solution, good for debug and a nop for release. I would like to share that with you.

Answer (score 0):

What I propose is to create an static constructor in the Program class (the class which has the Main method) and do the redirect there. This way we can quickly activate or deactivate it.

We can improve the solution maybe using Environment.CommandLine to parse the program arguments, looking for arguments starting with "<" or ">", but I prefer a more simple thing.

The following simple program uses this approach.

```
using System;

namespace RedirectConsoleSample
{
    class Program
    {
#if DEBUG
        static Program()
        {
            System.IO.TextReader oldConsoleTextReader = Console.In;
            System.IO.TextWriter oldConsoleTextWriter = Console.Out;
            System.IO.TextReader newConsoleTextReader = null;
            System.IO.TextWriter newConsoleTextWriter = null;

            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += delegate (object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.Out.Flush();
                    Console.SetOut(oldConsoleTextWriter);
                    Console.SetIn(oldConsoleTextReader);

                    if (newConsoleTextWriter != null)
                    {
                        newConsoleTextWriter.Close();
                        newConsoleTextWriter = null;
                    }

                    if (newConsoleTextReader != null)
                    {
                        newConsoleTextReader.Close();
                        newConsoleTextReader = null;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError("ProcessExit: " + ex.Message);
                }
            };

            newConsoleTextReader = new System.IO.StreamReader("Input.txt", System.Text.Encoding.Default, true);
            newConsoleTextWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter("Output.txt", false, System.Text.Encoding.Default);

            Console.Out.Flush();
            Console.SetIn(newConsoleTextReader);
            Console.SetOut(newConsoleTextWriter);
        }
#endif
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
                Console.Out.WriteLine("argument[{0}] = '{1}'", i, args[i]);

            for (string line = Console.In.ReadLine(); line != null; line = Console.In.ReadLine())
                Console.Out.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it can be useful.